# Abuse of notation when we denote $\mathcal{F}_n $-measurability of $X_n$ by "$X_n \in \mathcal{F}_n$"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am confused about a notation that I am seeing in many probability texts when authors write $X_n \in \mathcal{F}_n$ to express that $X_n$ is  $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. The elements in $\mathcal{F}_n$ are subsets of $\Omega$, our probability space, so it does not make any sense for $X_n$ to be an element of $\mathcal{F}_n$... If anything, what we should write is $X^{-1}_n(\omega) \in \mathcal{F}_n$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$ to denote $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurability. So my question is, do authors just write $X_n \in \mathcal{F}_n$ as some sort of shorthand convenience/abuse of notation, or am I missing something deeper here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I recall from general measure theory, a "measure space" is a set $X$ together with a $\sigma$-algebra $S$ on $X$, and a measure $\mu$ on $(X,S)$. In probability, you require $\mu(\varnothing)=0$ and $\mu(X)=1$. A subset of $X$ is "measurable" if it lies in $S$. A *function* between two measure spaces $f\colon (X,S,\mu)\to (Y,T,\nu)$ is measurable if for every measurable subset $B$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(Y)\in S$. So I do not understand your objection. A subset of $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable if it belongs to $\mathcal{F}_n$. "Measurable" is about subsets and functions. What is $X_n$?

Comment: I know one notation, where $f:X\to Y$ and $(X,\Sigma_1),(Y,\Sigma_2)$ are measurable spaces, for measurability is: “Let $f$ be $(\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2)$-measurable” for what it’s worth. It does appear an abuse of notation though

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: My objection is that $X_n$ in my context is a random variable, i.e. a function going from $\Omega$ (our probability space) to $\mathbb{R}$. How could $X_n$ possibly be a subset of $\Omega$? For any fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, $X_n^{-1}(\omega)$ gives us a subset of $\Omega$. So we should write $X_n^{-1}(\omega) \in \mathcal{F}_n$ for every $\omega$ to denote $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurability instead.

Comment: Ah, if it is a function, then it may be a bit of abuse of notation, though perhaps a trivial one.

Comment: I'm sorry to start about a stupid detail, but instead of $X_n^{-1}(\omega)\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$ shouldn't it be $X_n^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for every measurable subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$? If this is also standard notation, then I would say it is also an abuse of notation, since $X_n^{-1}$ could also be understood as the inverse of $X_n$.

Comment: I’d be curious to see a picture of where the book says this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a common abuse of notation in probability theory. I do not know the history of this notation, but I can give some arguments which suggest why it is sensible.

- With this notation, we have the implication$$
  X\in \mathcal F\text{ and }\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal G\implies X\in \mathcal G,
  $$
  which is what we would hope to be true for a binary relation notated with $\in$.
- To say that $X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable is to say that for all $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, that $X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F$. That is,
  $$
  X\in \mathcal F \iff X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F\text{ for all }B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)
  $$
  In other words, when we write $X\in \mathcal F$, we are not saying that $X$ itself is an element of $\mathcal F$, but that the inverse image of every Borel set under $X$ is an element of $\mathcal F$. 
  This is similar to how when we write $3\le X\le 5$, we are not saying that $X$ itself is an element of the closed interval $[3,5]$ (which is nonsense, since $X$ is a function, not a number), but rather that the image of every $\omega$ under $X$ is in this interval.
- A good intuition for $\sigma$-algebras is that they represent knowledge; knowing $\mathcal F$ means knowing, for each $A\in \mathcal F$, whether or not $A$ has occurred (that is, whether or not $\omega\in A$). If $X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, then knowing $\mathcal F$ gives you enough information to deduce $X(\omega)$. Therefore, we could roughly say that
  $$
  \text{The information needed to deduce $X$ is contained in $\mathcal F$,}
  $$
  but this is wordy, so we abbreviate it as $X\in \mathcal F$.

Whether you find these arguments convincing is a purely subjective matter.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you for breaking this down thoroughly and giving additional intuition. Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

$X_n\in \mathcal{F}_n$ is indeed an abuse of notation. THe correct statement is that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-$\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ measurable (for every Borel set $B\subset \Bbb{R}$, we require $X_n^{-1}(B):=\{\omega\in \Omega\,|\, X_n(\omega)\in B\}\in \mathcal{F}_n$).

Comment: btw I wouldn't be too worried about thinking that you're missing something. In my experience (reading Durrett and some other probability texts), if you think there's something off with the notation, you're probably going to be right (as compared to say if you read  a real-analysis text by Rudin/Folland)

Comment: Thank you for the reassuring comment. It's exactly like you said, when reading through my analysis textbook I noticed that notation was always extremely precise and consistent. In probability texts (we use Durrett in my class) I have definitely noticed a handful of cases where notation seems to be either hiding details or just conveying the wrong ideas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is a somewhat common abuse of notation/shorthand. It isn't too "out-there" if you consider that there is a canonical identification of events $E\in\mathcal F$ and their indicator functions $\mathbf 1_E(\omega) = 1$ if $\omega\in E$, and $0$ otherwise. Then a completely arbitrary $\mathcal F$-measurable random variable $X$ is a pointwise limit of (linear combinations of) such functions.

Comment: I think this is the most convincing reason.